# Qt: Clear previous drawings on repaint

Tags: macos, qt, qt5

I have a totally transparent, top-level, sreen-sized widget, which shows some text waterwarks on macOS. I need to update the system time text on one-minutes intervals. When I call the repaint method, the previously drawn text is not erased completely. Please see the attached image and demo project.

I've seen several posts on stackoverflow about this topic, but none of them works for me.
Could anyone show the most correct way to handle it with Qt? Thanks!
[image]

[demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6g94iygeifv7v2/untitled.zip?dl=1)

Comment: Re. `"When I call the repaint method, the previously drawn text is not erased completely"`: the code shown does not call `repaint`.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You set the widget's `Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent` attribute meaning `Qt` will not automatically erase the background before generating paint events.  You need to clear the background yourself.

Comment: I’ve tried every methods I can find online. Commenting out this line makes no difference.

Comment: You're also setting `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` which, from the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum), `"...causes WA_NoSystemBackground to be set"`.  Rather than commenting out the calls to `setAttribute` you should try clearing the background explicitly.

Comment: Could you please show me how to clear the background manually? I try to set composition to clear and call eraseRect, but it doesn’t work. Calling eraseRect directly would make the watermark disappear. I’m not an expert on Qt. Thanks!

Comment: As requested in the first comment you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've uploaded a demo project. Could you please take a look? I've tried many ways to clear background, but none of them works.

Comment: I've tried the example in the link and can't reproduce the problem on either `MacOS Darwin + Qt 5.14.2` or `Suse Linux + Qt 5.15.2`.

Comment: I'm using Qt 6.2.1 on macOS Moterey. Please take a look at the uploaded screenshot. There is a text watermark in a hollow effect left on the top.